# Core Data relationship delete rule - Nullify + Cascade

Tags: core-data, ios5

Entities:

- Video
- Playlist Item
- Playlist

Relationships:

- Video is optional to-many to Playlist Item and the delete rule is nullify
- Playlist is to-many to at least one Playlist Items and the delete rule is nullify
- Playlist Item is required to-one for Video and the delete rule is nullify
- Playlist Item is required to-one for Playlist and the delete rule is nullify

In the Playlist entity, I have not exposed the playlistItem relationship / set. Instead I have a transient undefined attribute called "videos," which is an array of Video entities generated by sorting the set of Playlist Items. There is not a relationship between Playlist and Video entities.

I'm having problems when saving a modified Playlist instance in the Managed Object Context.

*From playlist.m (NSManagedObject subclass):*

```
- (BOOL)validatePlaylistItems:(NSSet **)playlistItems error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSArray *currentVideos = [self videos];
    NSArray *persistedVideos = [self videosFromPlaylistItems];

    if ([currentVideos isEqual:persistedVideos]) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    for (FHPlaylistItem *pi in *playlistItems) {
        [context deleteObject:pi];
    }

    NSArray *videos = [self primitiveVideos];
    NSUInteger count = [videos count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        FHPlaylistItem *pi = [FHPlaylistItem playlistItemWithVideo:[videos objectAtIndex:i]
                                                          forIndex:i
                                    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        [self addPlaylistItemsObject:pi];
        [pi setPlaylist:self];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is only update the set of Playlist Items when the MOC needs to save, as you can see the operation is expensive - O(N * 2). During the first run of the app, the MOC saves just fine. However, subsequent changes to the videos attribute yields in Core Data spewing a bunch of errors:

```
Core Data: annotation: repairing missing delete propagation for to-many relationship playlistItems on object <FHPlaylist: 0x6c27eb0> (entity: Playlist; id: 0x6c26d40 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/Playlist/p19> ; data: {
    accountID = 0;
    lastFetched = "2012-03-31 20:05:08 +0000";
    name = Featured;
    playlistID = 1441335931001;
    playlistItems =     (
        "0x6c34be0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B2>",
        "0x6c34320 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p16>",
        "0x6c310c0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B3>",
        "0x6c35570 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B5>",
        "0x6c34ca0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B6>",
        "0x6c34310 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p8>",
        "0x6c28a90 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B4>",
        "0x6c34350 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p29>",
        "0x6c34220 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p2>",
        "0x6c34330 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p20>",
        "(...and 1 more...)"
    );
    playlistType = 0;
    referenceID = OKFFeaturedPlaylist;
    shortDescrip = "This is so descriptive! OMG!";
    thumbnailURL = nil;
    videos = "(...not nil..)";
}) with bad fault 0x6c34320 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p16>
Core Data: annotation: repairing missing delete propagation for to-many relationship playlistItems on object <FHPlaylist: 0x6c27eb0> (entity: Playlist; id: 0x6c26d40 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/Playlist/p19> ; data: {
    accountID = 0;
    lastFetched = "2012-03-31 20:05:08 +0000";
    name = Featured;
    playlistID = 1441335931001;
    playlistItems =     (
        "0x6c34be0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B2>",
        "0x6c310c0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B3>",
        "0x6c35570 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B5>",
        "0x6c34ca0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B6>",
        "0x6c34310 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p8>",
        "0x6c28a90 <x-coredata:///PlaylistItem/t9EAFBC87-5E16-4053-984F-881CCD9C1F0B4>",
        "0x6c34350 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p29>",
        "0x6c34220 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p2>",
        "0x6c34330 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p20>",
        "0x6c34340 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p27>"
    );
    playlistType = 0;
    referenceID = OKFFeaturedPlaylist;
    shortDescrip = "This is so descriptive! OMG!";
    thumbnailURL = nil;
    videos = "(...not nil..)";
}) with bad fault 0x6c34310 <x-coredata://BCB69D8E-8393-4A2A-AF5D-0AA1872CE2B4/PlaylistItem/p8>
Etc. Etc. Etc.
```

It seems to be the problem lies with the delete rule. The complaint is with a "missing delete propagation," so it seems nullify is the wrong choice. But, why is it wrong? This doesn't make sense to me. The wording of the cascade delete rule in [Apple's Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1) makes it seem like I'm going to delete the Video and Playlist objects if I set Playlist Item's delete rule to cascade.

> Cascade - Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship

<strike>Furthermore, if I set the relationship from Playlist Item to video & playlist to nil in the fast enumeration loop, Core Data doesn't complain about having to repair the missing delete propagation.</strike>

```
for (FHPlaylistItem *pi in *playlistItems) {
    [pi setVideo:nil];
    [pi setPlaylist:nil];
    [context deleteObject:pi];
}
```

EDIT: Nope, nil'ing the relationships manually didn't work in all situations. (Maybe no surprise?)

Comment: Same issue i am also facing. But after adding above method no change, still issue remain same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129364/core-data-after-adding-unique-constraint-annotation-repairing-missing-delet

Answer (score 10):

Try if [[self managedObjectContext] processPendingChanges] after your delete block will solve the strange messages for you.

It seems Core Data will get confused in some situations when you go on altering the managed object context in the same run loop cycle and some of the involved objects had relationships to the deleted objects.

Regards,

sven.

Comment: I just encountered this problem in my own code. Invoking -processingPendingChanges after the object deletion made Core Data quiet.

Comment: Same issue i am also facing. But after adding above method no change, still issue remain same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129364/core-data-after-adding-unique-constraint-annotation-repairing-missing-delet

Answer (score 1):

`-processPendingChanges` didn't work for me. What did work was to implement `-prepareForDeletion` in my NSManagedObject subclass and manually remove the object-to-be-deleted from the problematic to-many relationship:

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion {
    [[[self owningEntity] mutableSetValueForKey:@"ownedEntities"] removeObject:self];
}
```

I've triple-checked my data model and it looks OK. I don't know why this error is being produced. But this seems to make it disappear, at least.

Answer (score 0):

> On the Playlist entity, I have not exposed the playlistItem relationship / set. Instead I have a transient undefined attribute called "videos," which is an array of video generated by sorting the set of Playlist Items.

Maybe that's the problem. It's not clear how you've named the relationship to `Video`. If both  the relationship and the transient attribute are named `videos` you would definitely have a problem. Why not declare the `videos` relationship normally in `Playlist`'s h file, in addition to (rather than instead of) your declaration for, say, `videosSorted` (the transient array).

Also, make sure it's clear in the model which relationships are the inverse of each other.

Comment: There isn't a relationship from Playlist to Video. The videos array is generated from the Playlist to Playlist Items relationship. I've changed the wording to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

using performBlock fixed it for me:

```
[context performBlock:^{

// delete objects

// save context

}];
```