# Core Data (After Adding Unique Constraint) : annotation: repairing missing delete propagation for to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios9, unique-constraint

> This issue started occurring after we added Unique key i.es Constraint.

Frequently updating Meeting managed object deletes the event managed object which has a to-one inverse relationship from meeting managed object.

> Error CoreData: annotation: repairing missing delete propagation for to-many relationship meetingList on object 0x60c00009c4d0 (0x60c000621e40 ) with bad fault 0x60800009ac20 (0x60800023a360 )

Data Model

I have three entities in my core data model i.es

```
(CDEvent, CDMeeting, CDMLCheckin) .
```

Entity Properties and Relationship as described below:

Relationship
[image]

Properties:
CDEvent
[image]
CDMeeting
[image]

CDMLCheckin
[image]

**Unique Constraint:**

- CDEvent entity has **eventUUID** as unique constraint.
- CDMeeting entity has **meetingUUID** as unique constraint.

**Relationship**

- CDEvent <->>CDMeeting

  - From **CDEvent** to **CDMeeting** is to-many relationship with delete rule cascade, inverse relationship from CDMeeting to CDEvent is to-one with delete rule nullify.
- CDEvent <->>CDMLCheckin

  - From **CDEvent** to **CDMLCheckin** is to-many relationship with delete rule cascade, inverse relationship from CDMLCheckin to CDEvent is to-one with delete rule nullify.

Full Description : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2DQhBBLqjAP9eWbx5YpQhH7oVigxT_mcJDnPLlOMtQ/edit?usp=sharing

**Note**

- If i remove Unique Constraint **eventUUID** from **CDEvent** everything works fine.

Please help us here as we are struck from more than a week :(

Comment: Same issue, even i am also facing. If anyone know the solution kindly help me.....

Answer (score 2):

I hope I can help, having a unique constraint with To-Many Relationship Entities you need to keep some points in mind

- Use Inverse Relationship of every CoreData relation
- Unique Constrains Attributes should never be Optional

When you create NSManagedObjectContext make sure you set MergePolicy.

[_context setMergePolicy: mergePolicy];

- NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
- NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
- NSOverwriteMergePolicy

Also could you try changing the nullify delete rule to no action ?

Comment: I did all these after setting unique constraint from the tutorial but still facing the same issue.
Also, I cannot set delete rule to No action because it will lead to dangling pointer

Comment: by setting the unique constraint eventUUID you make it mandatory so the cascade rule will fail. Did you try changing the name "eventUUID" from the CDMeeting and CDMLCheckin tables so you won't make it mandatory. Apple docs. "You can also specify constraints on relationships, such as making them mandatory or unable exceed a certain number." I had the same problem about 6 month ago and I fix it by implementing my own deletion algorithm. When is the error throw ? I only saw in the documentation the deletion for CDMLCheckin

Comment: @lonescu Vlad, i have tried to rename the eventUUID but not success. Can you explain how can i implement my own deletion algorithm.

Comment: Could you make like a demo git, it would be much easier

Comment: I forgot to mention, As i have one more entity "CDEventMetaData" which has to-one relationship with "CDEvent", issue raise when i try to update the "CDEventMetaData"entity. Kindly check the docs at page 16, i have update the logs of "CDEvent" class methods. @IonescuVlad

Comment: @IonescuVlad : Any updates as we are facing this issue from a couple of weeks and it's really annoying?

Comment: Please add a git demo , as I’m facing a ton of work , and I won’t have time to build it from scratch.